# What does this unnamed static cryptic syntax mean?

Tags: java

In this NotePadProvider sample code, I noticed that inside the class there is a static block **without any name** and **without any type**:

```
static {
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(NotePad.AUTHORITY, "notes", NOTES);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(NotePad.AUTHORITY, "notes/#", NOTE_ID);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(NotePad.AUTHORITY, "live_folders/notes", LIVE_FOLDER_NOTES);

    sNotesProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sNotesProjectionMap.put(NoteColumns._ID, NoteColumns._ID);
    sNotesProjectionMap.put(NoteColumns.TITLE, NoteColumns.TITLE);
    sNotesProjectionMap.put(NoteColumns.NOTE, NoteColumns.NOTE);
    sNotesProjectionMap.put(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE, NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE);
    sNotesProjectionMap.put(NoteColumns.MODIFIED_DATE, NoteColumns.MODIFIED_DATE);

    // Support for Live Folders.
    sLiveFolderProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sLiveFolderProjectionMap.put(LiveFolders._ID, NoteColumns._ID + " AS " +
            LiveFolders._ID);
    sLiveFolderProjectionMap.put(LiveFolders.NAME, NoteColumns.TITLE + " AS " +
            LiveFolders.NAME);
    // Add more columns here for more robust Live Folders.
}
```

What does this `static { }` mean?

Also, what is the advantage of using this terse syntax over a more readable syntax (I am only assuming such one exists, I don't know that for sure until the first question is answered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the static initializer of the class. It is executed only once. When? The first time you ever use that class in your application.

The idea is to construct some variables, structures, data, etc... (whatever you like) that will be used across all the instances of that class. Or, for example, simply construct a lookup table for sine values.

There are several ways it gets invoked. All of these situations:

- `new MyClass();` first calls the static initializer and then the constructor
- `Class.forName("my.package.MyClass");`
- `MyClass.staticMethodCallHere();`
- `MyClass.class.methodCallHere();`

Comment: Thanks. Is this executed before the constructor of the class? Is there an alternative syntax for this?

Comment: It's not related to the constructor. The constructor of the class doesn't need to be invoked in order for this static block to be executed. Being a static block it initializes only the static parts of the class, it has nothing to do with the instance vars of the class (as the constructor has).

Comment: OK I got it now. The fact that the author of that sample placed that `static { }` at the end of the class is really confusing.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: I was just answering ateiob's comment. It had nothing to do with your answer.

Comment: @Razvan: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't got it :D Apologizes.

Answer (score 1):

What this static {} block is good for?

if you have a static member, then you can create it without this block like:

```
static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

but you can't do anything else with it. This initializer block enables you to commit manipulation on your static stuff:

```
static List<Integer> list; // = new ArrayList<Integer>();

static
{
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)  // just an example
        list.add(i);
}
```

Comment: i noticed it before, and corrected it, but thanks :) it's easier to understand like this

Comment: This is interesting because this allows to initialize a const at runtime. i.e. even if List is declared `static final`.